# The installed iOS app can run in the device in-spite its provisioning profile has deleted from Developer portal

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have a very worst scenario. I have built one enterprise iOS app and the app is installed in too many number of devices. Now the respected provisioning profile is expiring on 2nd of March 2015 so my client has suggested that please remove the existing profile and create new provisioning profile on 2nd Feb 2015.

So i just want to confirm that,

1. If i delete the provisioning profile from developer portal then the already installed app in users devices using this deleted profile will stop running or not ?
2. How can i manage this thing so users can run the existing application and they do not require to install new application that will be built using new provisioning profile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need to delete the provisioning profile ? Is your app in AppStore or it's an AdHoc distribution ?

Comment: it's an enterprise application so we have distributed the app using enterprise distribution certificate. It's not on appStore.

Answer (score 1):

> If i delete the provisioning profile from developer portal then the
>   already installed app in users devices using this deleted profile will
>   stop running or not ?

No, it won't stop. (until the expiration date)

> How can i manage this thing so users can run the existing application
>   and they do not require to install new application that will be built
>   using new provisioning profile.

You can't, you need to provide a new build with newly created certificate and provisioning profile.

Comment: The one thing I'll add to Midhun's answer is that if the deployment by the company used MDM, you could give the provisioning profile to the company, they'd distribute it by MDM wirelessly, and there would be no need to push a new build of the app and force users to update themselves.  If this company is large enough, they really should be using MDM anyway so as to push updates to their enterprise app users as they are released and without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the existing provisioning profile from developer portal then the already installed app will not stop running.

You can go to the Provisioning Portal ( http://developer.apple.com/ ) on the apple site and delete the existing profile and create a new one.